# Apply custom css to Sharepoint 2013 page

Tags: sharepoint-designer, css

I'm very new to Sharepoint programming so I appologize if my question sounds stupid.

How can I add a custom css stylesheet to my site's pages? Are there any free tools to help me customize my site and site elements like lists - to add css rules for a view for example?

I am working with an on-premises Sharepoint server running on Windows Server 2012.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this should be done using Visual Studio 2012-2013 or you can hack at it using SharePoint Designer.

I am currently doing the hacking part and believe me if i had the time i would go back and do it the visual studio way.

When adding CSS to any aspx page ensure you use:

If you want to apply CSS styles to a page layout per device channel use the below:

-->
    
        
        -->
        -->

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="MyStyleSheet.css" ms-design-css-conversion="no" />
    <!--ME:</Publishing:DeviceChannelPanel>-->
    <!--CE: End Device Channel Panel Snippet-->

</div><div data-name="DeviceChannelPanel">
    <!--CS: Start Device Channel Panel Snippet-->
    <!--SPM:<%@Register Tagprefix="Publishing" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,      PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>-->
    <!--MS:<Publishing:DeviceChannelPanel runat="server" IncludedChannels="Channel2">-->

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS5.css" />
     <!--ME:</Publishing:DeviceChannelPanel>-->
     <!--CE: End Device Channel Panel Snippet-->
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand this post actually, is it possible there's code missing?

Comment: Yes code is missing, use this page as a reference http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj822368%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Comment: Using Visual Studio just to add CSS to a SharePoint page is probably an extreme case of overkill... especially for simple scenarios or newer SP users. There are probably 10 ways to accomplish this without VS, all of which are easier to implement, and some of which provide just as robust results across different sites/webs/tenants

Answer (score 3):

Well, since version 2013, SharePoint has implemented a new feature called the Design Manager to make it easier for people who have no experience with SharePoint to implement their own custom styles. You enable the Design Manager by enable the publishing feature.

To enable the design manager follow the next steps:

1. Click on the gear icon in the top right and click "Site settings"
2. In the next page, under "Site Collection Administration" click "Site collection features"
3. Find "SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure" and click "Activate"
4. Go back to the previous page (Site settings) and go to "Manage site features" under "Site Actions"
5. Find "SharePoint Server Publishing" and click "Activate"

After you've followed these steps, click on the gear icon again in the top right and you should a new option called the "Design Manager", when you click this you will go through a process that takes you through the various SharePoint design options available to you. It is it's own step by step guide for teaching people like yourself the basics. Make sure you follow each step carefully and make sure you follow the tutorials on each page.